# Python decorator scope

Tags: python-3.x, scope, decorator

I am trying to understand logic of decorators in Python and i am having trouble with scope of local variable.
**CODE:**

```
# version #1
def decorator(function):
    counter = 0
    def wrapper():
        print(counter)
        function()
        return counter
    return wrapper

# version #2
def decorator(function):
    counter = 0
    def wrapper():
        counter += 1
        function()
        return counter
    return wrapper

@decorator
def function():
    print("Printed from function().")

function()
```

My question is, why `#1` works and `counter` is printed, but when i try to change `counter` in `#2`, i get `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'counter' referenced before assignment`?
Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

`counter += 1` is a sugar of `counter = counter + 1` which defines a variable `counter` equal to 1+`counter` which is unbound at that moment.